# Is there a way I can make a exe, bat or other file in Windows type to change the cursor to 'busy' after execution?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cursor

I am trying to simulate a busy window or even more simple, a busy cursor by executing a file that will change the cursor for a set amount of time. I would like to be able to control the amount of time the cursor is on 'busy'. Any ideas?

Comment: Look at [`SetCursor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648393(v=vs.85).aspx) but realize that the cursor is a shared resource, and you really should only change it when it's under your control (i.e. in your window) and read [The Old New Thing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/05/25/421707.aspx) for some more caveats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create an [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com) script.

Use this [`SetSystemCursor`](http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/topic35600.html) function and add the following at the top in the auto-execute section:

```
#NoTrayIcon
#Persistent

DefaultBusyTime := 1000
SetSystemCursor("IDC_WAIT")
If %0% > 1
    SetTimer,RestoreSystemCursor,-%1%
Else
    SetTimer,RestoreSystemCursor,-%DefaultBusyTime%
Return

RestoreSystemCursor:
    SetSystemCursor("Restore")
    ExitApp
Return
```

Complete script: [busycursor.ahk](https://gist.github.com/tamamshud/5248137)

Compile to a standalone executable:

```
Ahk2Exe.exe /in busycursor.ahk /out busycursor.exe
```

Pass the busy wait time in milliseconds as an argument:

```
busycursor 2500
```

Comment: thank you so much. is there a way to get the animation for the busy cursor to work as well? Again, I really appreciate it.

Comment: @user2167823 Call `SetSystemCursor` with the path to any animated cursor file. E.g. `SetSystemCursor("C:\Windows\Cursors\aero_busy.ani")`. Also, replace `LoadImageA` with `LoadImage`.

Answer (score 0):

Would creating a batch file and placing the statement of "TIMEOUT 60" work for you?  The 60 is simply the number of seconds so you can adjust to whatever you need.

If this doesn't provide the "busy" state you are looking for, you could also create a for loop in the batch file that counted to some fixed number, then exits.